# Промежуточные даты в sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, дата

Есть таблица выполненных операций orders, в котором хранятся все операции со счетом пользователя т.е зачисление, списание и т.д Выгялдит она соотвественно так.
`| id | userId | Date | Summ | Wallet`.
`| 1  |  72    |  13  | 20   |   N`   .
`| 2  |  72    |  13  | 20   |   T`   .
`| 3  |  72    |  15  | -20  |   N`   .
`| 4  |  72    |  16  | -20  |   T`   .
`| 5  |  26    |  15  | 10   |   N`   .
`| 6  |  26    |  15  | 10   |   T`   .
`| 7  |  26    |  18  | -10  |   T`   .
`| 8  |  26    |  21  | -10  |   N`   .
N - не торговый счет.
T - торговый счет.
Задача стоит следущая: `Вывести все операции по дням включая промежуточные` т.е была операция по счету `id = 1` и конец этой операции `id=3`. Поясняю было зачисление на `неторговый счет` 20ед. `13 числа`, а списание с неторгового счета этого же пользователя  было `15 числа`. Нужно вывести промежуточные даты включая даты операций т.е 13-14-15.
Написал `sql` запрос следущего формата:

```
set @Date1 = '01/01/2022'
set @Date2 = '01/31/2022'
Declare @Date datetime
Select @Date = Convert(datetime, @Date1)
While @Date <= Convert(datetime, @Date2)
Begin
  Select userId, @Date As Data, Summ, Wallet, 0 As PaymentSum, 0 As TransitSum
  From table 
  Where Data <= @Date 

  Select @Date = @Date + 1  
End
```

Результат запроса выводит лишние даты, т.е если по примеру `id=1 и id=3` выводит не `13-14-15`, а `13-14-15-16-17` и т.д до значения `@Date2`.
Подскажите как правильно написать запрос, сам в `sql` не силен и не представляю как решить данный ворос, задачку надо решить именно в `sql` т.к данные дальше экспортируются в `word`

Comment: В CTE генерируете календарь в диапазоне дат таблицы. В другом CTE объединяете начальную и конечную записи (или формируете сумму с накоплением - из описания непонятно, что именно требуется). А в основном запросе просто объединяете результаты по попаданию даты календаря в диапазон дат между началом и концом действий.

Comment: *Выгялдит она соотвественно так.* [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант. Немного добавил данных:

| id | userId | Date | Summ | Wallet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 72 | 13 | 20 | N |
| 2 | 72 | 13 | 20 | T |
| 3 | 72 | 15 | -20 | N |
| 4 | 72 | 16 | -20 | T |
| 5 | 26 | 15 | 10 | N |
| 6 | 26 | 15 | 10 | T |
| 7 | 26 | 18 | -10 | T |
| 8 | 26 | 21 | -10 | N |
| 9 | 101 | 2 | 20,00 | N |
| 10 | 101 | 2 | 7,00 | T |
| 11 | 101 | 2 | 20,00 | N |
| 12 | 101 | 5 | -40,00 | N |
| 13 | 101 | 4 | -3,00 | T |
| 14 | 101 | 6 | -4,00 | T |

Код:

```
-- Задаём период
DECLARE
  @Date1 DATETIME = '20220101',
  @Date2 DATETIME = '20220131'

-- Создаём табличку с тестовыми данными
DECLARE
  @MovementTable TABLE (
      Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
      UserId INT,
      MoveDate DATETIME, -- нехорошо всё-таки имя столбца date называть, лучше в конце переименуем
      Summ MONEY,
      Wallet CHAR(1)
  )
-- Наполняем тестовыми данными

INSERT @MovementTable
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  (72, '20220113', 20, 'N'),
  (72, '20220113', 20, 'T'),
  (72, '20220115', -20, 'N'),
  (72, '20220116', -20, 'T'),
  (26, '20220115', 10, 'N'),
  (26, '20220115', 10, 'T'),
  (26, '20220118', -10, 'T'),
  (26, '20220121', -10, 'N'),
  (101, '20220102', 20, 'N'),
  (101, '20220102', 7, 'T'),
  (101, '20220102', 20, 'N'),
  (101, '20220105', -40, 'N'),
  (101, '20220104', -3, 'T'),
  (101, '20220106', -4, 'T')
) T(UserId, MoveDate, Summ, Wallet)

-- просматривает содержимое тестовых данных, потом удалить
SELECT * FROM @MovementTable

-- Собственно сам запрос
;WITH GenDates AS(
    SELECT @Date1 CalcDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CalcDate + 1
    FROM GenDates
    WHERE CalcDate < @Date2
)

SELECT 
  MT.Id, -- ид записи в исходной таблице
  GroupT.UserId,
  MT.CalcDate AS [Date], -- вот тут уже можно переименовать, если этого ворд ждёт
  MT.Summ,
  GroupT.Wallet
FROM ( -- для каждой пары UserId-Wallet ищём диапазон дат
  SELECT UserId, Wallet,
    MIN(MoveDate)MinDate,
    MAX(MoveDate)MaxDate
  FROM @MovementTable MT
  GROUP BY UserId, Wallet
) GroupT CROSS APPLY(
  -- соединяем с последовательностью дат в этом диапазоне
  SELECT MT.*, GD.CalcDate
  FROM GenDates GD
    LEFT JOIN @MovementTable MT ON GroupT.UserId = MT.UserId AND GroupT.Wallet = MT.Wallet 
      AND MT.MoveDate = GD.CalcDate
  WHERE GD.CalcDate BETWEEN GroupT.MinDate AND GroupT.MaxDate
) MT
-- сортируем
ORDER BY GroupT.UserId, GroupT.Wallet, MT.CalcDate, MT.Id

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 3650)-- 10 лет думаю хватит :)
```

Результат:

| Id | UserId | Date | Summ | Wallet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 26 | 2022-01-15 00:00:00.000 | 10,00 | N |
| NULL | 26 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00.000 | NULL | N |
| NULL | 26 | 2022-01-17 00:00:00.000 | NULL | N |
| NULL | 26 | 2022-01-18 00:00:00.000 | NULL | N |
| NULL | 26 | 2022-01-19 00:00:00.000 | NULL | N |
| NULL | 26 | 2022-01-20 00:00:00.000 | NULL | N |
| 8 | 26 | 2022-01-21 00:00:00.000 | -10,00 | N |
| 6 | 26 | 2022-01-15 00:00:00.000 | 10,00 | T |
| NULL | 26 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00.000 | NULL | T |
| NULL | 26 | 2022-01-17 00:00:00.000 | NULL | T |
| 7 | 26 | 2022-01-18 00:00:00.000 | -10,00 | T |
| 1 | 72 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00.000 | 20,00 | N |
| NULL | 72 | 2022-01-14 00:00:00.000 | NULL | N |
| 3 | 72 | 2022-01-15 00:00:00.000 | -20,00 | N |
| 2 | 72 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00.000 | 20,00 | T |
| NULL | 72 | 2022-01-14 00:00:00.000 | NULL | T |
| NULL | 72 | 2022-01-15 00:00:00.000 | NULL | T |
| 4 | 72 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00.000 | -20,00 | T |
| 9 | 101 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 20,00 | N |
| 11 | 101 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 20,00 | N |
| NULL | 101 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000 | NULL | N |
| NULL | 101 | 2022-01-04 00:00:00.000 | NULL | N |
| 12 | 101 | 2022-01-05 00:00:00.000 | -40,00 | N |
| 10 | 101 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 7,00 | T |
| NULL | 101 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00.000 | NULL | T |
| 13 | 101 | 2022-01-04 00:00:00.000 | -3,00 | T |
| NULL | 101 | 2022-01-05 00:00:00.000 | NULL | T |
| 14 | 101 | 2022-01-06 00:00:00.000 | -4,00 | T |

Comment: Искал медь, а нашел золото!